# Parse function `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:` retrieves some of the database objects, but not all

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform, objective-c-blocks

I have a function, shown below, that should retrieve all the "Food" objects from my parse database.  However, while the actual database currently has 249 objects, the block retrieves only 100 objects.

```
- (void) addFoodsToArray:(NSMutableArray*)targetArray {

    PFQuery * foodQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Food"];

    [foodQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray * foods, NSError * error) {

            for (PFObject *foodRaw in foods) {
                MenuItem *food = [[MenuItem alloc] initWithName:[foodRaw valueForKey:@"name"]  andURL:nil];
                [targetArray addObject:food];
            }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Dude. check the method that you have given `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`. If it is coreData you are using, check batch size.

Comment: It's not core data, I'm using a 3rd party host called parse.com to store my data.  `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is one of the functions they provide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

100 results is the default when querying with Parse.
You can set the limit to be higher by setting

```
foodQuery.limit = 1000;
```

(1000 being the maximum number of results).

Check [Parse Documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-constraints/iOS)  for more info.